# Is there anyway to set a different value for the "input" than the vue variable?

Tags: vue.js

I need to change the display of a input depending on the value returned from the db for this variable: `paragraph.RCBulletinNumber`

I have tried the computed method, but I think this is not what I need

```
     computed: {

    formatRCBulletinNumber: {

        set (val){
            return this.paragraph.RCBulletinNumber;
        }

    }

},
```

This is my input declaration using v-model='paragraph.RCBulletinNumber':

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div v-if='typeof paragraph != undefined /*/<!--&& parseInt(paragraph.RCBulletinNumber)>0 -->/*/'>
            <input type="text" style="width: 40%;" class='form-control' id="RCNumber" placeholder="RC Number" v-model='paragraph.RCBulletinNumber'>
                </div>
                    </div>
```

What I expect is that if the value of `paragraph.RCBulletinNumber` is less than or equal to 0 the input remains empty. Right now if the variable equals 0 the input is 0

But if the `paragraph.RCBulletinNumber` is equal to 0, the value must go to the database again, my goal is just to change the value of the input to be more userfriendly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `set()` function??

Comment: for example, If this were pure js, I would just do [ if(myvalue<=0) {$("id").val("");} else{$("id").val(myvalue);}

What I need is to have the variable paragraph.RCBulletinNumber without any modification, but if its input is 0 or less leave it empty (Just the frontend, the input, without touching the variable).

Answer (score 2):

Simply define the getter and setter of the computed property:

```
computed: {
  formatRCBulletinNumber: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.paragraph.RCBulletinNumber || '';
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      this.paragraph.RCBulletinNumber = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

And then reference the computed property on the input:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 40%;" class='form-control' id="RCNumber" placeholder="RC Number" v-model='formatRCBulletinNumber'>
```

reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter